# Using awk in a bash script to select line range based on number of characters in specific line

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

This seems like something that might be possible in a single long awk command. But I don't know awk well enough to do it.

I want to identify the total number of `A`, `T`, `G` and `C` characters in every 4th line of input, starting from line 2. If any line number that is a multiple of 4, has a character count in the range say 1000 to 3000, then I want it to print that line as well as the line above and the two lines below.

I can break it down and do portions of this in separate lines of code. But when I have millions of lines, it takes too long to compute. I need a single powerful awk command here. There must be someone brilliant enough at awk to solve this one!

Very tiny example, with range `10 < character count < 40`:
Input:

```
@d0aec33d-ba    
TCAGTATGCTTCGTGCAATCAAG    
+    
-0(''$&"('    
@ee487ad3-b71    
ACAATGTG    
+    
""%#0&'+367<677
```

Output:

```
@d0aec33d-ba    
TCAGTATGCTTCGTGCAATCAAG    
+    
-0(''$&"('
```

Comment: Can there be any characters other than `A`, `T`, `G` or `C` in the 4th line?

Comment: I have no idea what your requirements mean and I can't imagine how any interpretation of them could produce the expected output you posted from the sample input you posted. idk if others are having more luck but you might want to clarify what you're trying to do and explain why that's the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick one:

```
$ awk '
NR%4==1 { b="" }                                # first record of four, reset buffer
NR%4==2 && length()>10 && length()<40 { f=1 }   # 2/4 if length is right, flag up
{ b=b $0 ORS }                                  # buffer records to b
NR%4==0 && f {                                  # 4/4 
    printf "%s",b                               # print if flag is up
    f=0                                         # and flag down
}' file
```

Output:

```
@d0aec33d-ba
TCAGTATGCTTCGTGCAATCAAG
+
-0(''$&"('
```

**Edit**:

A parameterized version (`x=$min`, `y=$max`):

```
$ awk -v x=$min -v y=$max '
NR%4==1 { b="" }                                # first record of four, reset buffer
NR%4==2 && length()>x && length()<y { f=1 }     # 2/4 if length is right, flag up
{ b=b $0 ORS }                                  # buffer records to b
NR%4==0 && f {                                  # 4/4 
    printf "%s",b         #                     # print if flag is up
    f=0                 # #                     # and flag down
    # printf b; f=0   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # if commands on the same line                        
}' file                 # #
                          #
```

One-liner just in case:

```
$ awk -v x=$min -v y=$max 'NR%4==1{b=""} NR%4==2 && length()>x && length()<y{f=1} {b=b $0 ORS} NR%4==0 && f{printf "%s",b; f=0}' file
```

Comment: wow that was quick, I haven't tested it on a larger data set yet, but I can't see where it takes into account the <40 parameter though

Comment: Fixed. Used the waterfall model :D

Comment: ooooooooo that looks pretty, I wish I was more efficient with awk. I'm going to quickly test this on a portion of the data, will let you know if there are any hicups

Comment: AFK in 2 mins for about an hour.

Comment: you've given a great explanation, but I don't think I understand awk well enough to implement it. edited the code to take variables and deal with some syntax errors that were popping up. But produces an empty output when applied to a file.     awk -v x=$MinBufferedExpectedFragSize -v y=$MaxBufferedExpectedFragSize 'NR%4==1 { b="" }; NR%4==2 && length()>x && length()<y { f=1 };{ b=b $0 ORS };NR%4==0 && f {printf b f==0}'

Comment: @Giles `length()>x && length()<y` - shouldn't this be `length()>$x && length()<$y`? Also, your command seems to be missing the `file` portion of @JamesBrown's command `awk '{ ... }' file`, although you may have left it off for brevity.

Comment: Hi Jonny, as far as I'm aware you have to call variables in the preliminary stage of awk using -v. then when using the new variable alias later within the awk command you don't use the '$' sign. so set variable -v x=$MinBufferedExpectedFragSize, then just use 'x' with no '$'. yeah I skipped 'file' in comments, as classified as a given, but you're right, it would have been a major problem if it wasn't something skipped for brevity

Comment: @Giles oh sorry, I overlooked that the assignments to `x` and `y` were part of the `awk` command. Nothing in the code you posted in your comment is jumping out as obviously wrong. Which makes me think it's either a small variable assignment problem or the input file is not in the proper format (i.e. every 4th line after the 2nd line is not a `TCAG` line). Have you checked, via `echo`, if `$MinBufferedExpectedFragSize` and `$MaxBufferedExpectedFragSize` are set to the values you expect?

Comment: I'm back. Added parameterized version, works over here. You mentioned some syntax errors?

Comment: The final block (`{printf b f==0}` in your comment) is wrong. It should have a semicolon if the commands are on the same line and a `=` instead of `==`, ie: `{printf b; f==0}`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I ran it with your adjustments and got a new error (long path and file removed for easier read): awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file path / file FNR=600) fatal: arg count with `$' must be > 0

Comment: Why would line 600 not > 0, the line starts like this: #%$%&#)$+)/'/019$,+4;)/$1"(.-019:9:896.,%)('/>;;<*+.,-3;,::66%&(+,:42965&9<69.41212.76<:(.((7.+-+2,3,+/;,640137181004.+&(/',-.-960)&',+,68>5/**).##%"&*)#,())-,2(*+:6,),-00/<<=67/8<96/$"(()*,*%"%.594&*$+1.+("&%',11/.-*+-.)57/(+0168:-;8(-))-'%#%&21<-...+),0-445167/$0.088'&""&+-;<<,)/1.82&&$#$&)++.-84--%'&&-.3*+-:+00.0))-/0>;<3*#$%+';8+<=<'22;689+*(**33699<**-*'(#"-)*+2.3.-3<408.*)08866665276&&")%***.)'.

Comment: It's probably the `printf b`. Replacing it with `printf "%s",b` should fix that.

Comment: Worked like a charm, great fix, beautiful code James!